# N8 touch scroll lwuit

Tags: lwuit

I develop with lwuit to Nokia and Blackberry.

I have a problem with touch scrolling in the device N8.
The scroll is terrible. Its jump to the end of the list any time that i use in the scroll and also the focus on the cells don't active to the scroll.

In the device Nokia c3 i don't have this problem.

do anyone recognize this problem?

it is solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is usually triggered by bad performance, S60 is surprisingly slower than S40 and thus the code that processes touch behavior just miscalculates the speed of the gesture.

The [codename one developer guide](http://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html) contains quite a few tips on performance which are applicable to S60. Some of these fixes (such as 9-part border sizes) are already builtin to Codename One's designer. Codename One also has a builtin UI speed measurement tool so you are better off porting to Codename One than staying with LWUIT.